# How long is long for the Unix 'file' command?

Tags: unix, shell

When you pass a text file to the Unix `file` command, it might tell you something like:

```
input.txt: UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines
```

Can somebody tell me the minimum number of characters a line must contain to be considered *very long*? The man pages don't say anything about this and I don't want to search the source code. If someone can tell me how to put this question into a Google query which doesn't return a billion results, almost all of which are irrelevant, I'd be happy, too.

Comment: Vote to move to superuser due to the reluctance to search the source code.

Comment: You guys have a point - I'll search the source code next time. Thanks, anyways!

Answer (score 24):

**From `ascmagic.c` in the *file* source package on Ubuntu:**

```
#include "names.h"

#define MAXLINELEN 300  /* longest sane line length */
#define ISSPC(x) ((x) == ' ' || (x) == '\t' || (x) == '\r' || (x) == '\n' \
          || (x) == 0x85 || (x) == '\f')
```

Seems like a line needs to be more than 300 characters to be considered "very long".

Answer (score 7):

Over 300 chacracters, according to lines 52 and 214-215 in ascmagic.c in the source code.

The source code can be found here (link fetched from the Debian man page for `file`):
ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/

Answer (score 7):

Brute force (plus this is a program, right? so it makes it programming related?):

```
$ for i in {1..301}; do printf "%${i}s" "." | file - | grep very && echo $i; done
/dev/stdin: very short file (no magic)
1
/dev/stdin: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
301
```

Answer (score 2):

A line is considered long if it has more than 300 characters.